# How to Create a Dockerfile file using Rhel

Tags: java, dockerfile, rhel7

I am creating google cloud VM using rhel7 and install docker after try to build docker image using dockerfile image not build docker.

```
FROM rhel
RUN yum update -y
yum install -y \
   java-1.8.0-openjdk \
   java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel
ENV JAVA_HOME /etc/alternatives/jre
```

Error response from daemon: Unknown instruction: .

Answer (score 0):

You can use,

```
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/rhel7/rhel
MAINTAINER John W. Jones <jjones@example.com>
# Add Web server, update image, and clear cache
RUN yum -y install httpd && yum -y update; yum clean all
# Add some data to web server
RUN echo "This Web server is working." > /var/www/html/index.html
EXPOSE 80
ENTRYPOINT [ "/usr/sbin/httpd" ]
CMD [ "-D", "FOREGROUND" ]
```

([ref](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux_atomic_host/7/html/getting_started_with_containers/using_red_hat_base_container_images_standard_and_minimal).)